# Yii2 Separating ApiController

Tags: php, api, controller, yii2

I have the next structure in project: `controllers -> ApiController.php`
so, when I call some endpoint, that use like `<host>/api/<endpoint>`
I need to separate this controller to several controllers like: `UserApiController / BooksApiController` etc, but then it will change the path for calling endpoint to `<host>/user-api/<endpoint>`. How can I keep this path `/api/` for separated api's controllers?

Comment: you could take a look at modules

Comment: @ScaisEdge as I understand even with modules the path will be changed. I need solution without changes with the path

Comment: With modules you can have `UserController` in api module, so you would end with `<host>/api/user/<action>`. Or if you use REST api, which uses HTTP methods to determine action you will have `<host>/api/user` or `<host>/api/user/<id>`. If that's not enough for you, you will have to create a specific url rule for each action.